# double precision no truncation when typecast to int

Tags: java, casting, precision

The following:

```
double x = .43;
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(z);
System.out.println(bd);
```

outputs:

```
.4299999.....
```

why does

```
 double u = z*100;
 bd = new BigDecimal(u);
 System.out.println(u);
```

output:

```
 43?
```

more generally I'm trying to find a case where the double representation causes a truncation problem.  Consider the following:

```
double d;
int j;
BigDecimal bd;
for(int i = 0; i<10000;i++){
   d= (double)(i/100.);
   j = (int)(d*100.);
   bd = new BigDecimal(j);
   System.out.println(bd);
}
```

In not a single case is truncating occurring

Comment: **Do not** use [`new BigDecimal(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#%3Cinit%3E(double)). Use [`BigDecimal.valueOf(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf(double)). The javadoc says so too.

Comment: `System.out.println(u);`   <-- there is a typo, should be `println(bd)`

Comment: Where do you set `z` and what is its type?

Comment: And I think it's OK to use whichever constructor you like for `BigDecimal`, so long as you understand floating point arithmetic, and know exactly what each constructor does.

Comment: @Andreas wow, that is a really gross difference. I use neither, but I might have assumed they differed only in caching (as the `new Double(double)` and `Double.valueOf(double)` do).

Comment: I assume `double x = .43;` should be `z`?

Comment: @AndyTurner `BigDecimal` violates multiple normal conventions. E.g. [`a.equals(b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [`a.compareTo(b) == 0`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo(java.math.BigDecimal)) is not the same thing, i.e. `compareTo` is not consistent with `equals`, and it's really the `compareTo` most people needs, same as it is the `valueOf` most people needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In not a single case is truncating occurring

That is incorrect. Truncation occurs many times, you just didn't look close enough.

E.g. for `i = 29`:

```
int i = 29;
double d= i / 100.;
int j = (int)(d * 100.);
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(j);
System.out.println(bd);
```

*Output*

```
28
```

***OOPS!!!***

Though I don't know what the point of converting `j` to `bd` is, since [`new BigDecimal(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#%3Cinit%3E(int)) is always exact.

If you want to see all the truncation errors, try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
    double d = i / 100.;
    int j = (int)(d * 100.);
    if (i != j)
        System.out.println(i + ": " + j);
}
```

*Output*

```
29: 28
57: 56
58: 57
113: 112
114: 113
115: 114
116: 115
201: 200
203: 202
205: 204
207: 206
226: 225
228: 227
230: 229
232: 231
251: 250
253: 252
255: 254
402: 401
406: 405
410: 409
414: 413
427: 426
431: 430
435: 434
439: 438
452: 451
456: 455
460: 459
464: 463
477: 476
481: 480
485: 484
489: 488
502: 501
506: 505
510: 509
803: 802
804: 803
812: 811
820: 819
828: 827
829: 828
837: 836
845: 844
853: 852
854: 853
862: 861
870: 869
878: 877
879: 878
887: 886
895: 894
903: 902
904: 903
912: 911
920: 919
928: 927
929: 928
937: 936
945: 944
953: 952
954: 953
962: 961
970: 969
978: 977
979: 978
987: 986
995: 994
1003: 1002
1004: 1003
1012: 1011
1020: 1019
1606: 1605
1608: 1607
1615: 1614
1624: 1623
1631: 1630
1633: 1632
1640: 1639
1649: 1648
1656: 1655
1658: 1657
1665: 1664
1674: 1673
1681: 1680
1683: 1682
1690: 1689
1699: 1698
1706: 1705
1708: 1707
1715: 1714
1724: 1723
1731: 1730
1733: 1732
1740: 1739
1749: 1748
1756: 1755
1758: 1757
1765: 1764
1774: 1773
1781: 1780
1783: 1782
1790: 1789
1799: 1798
1806: 1805
1808: 1807
1815: 1814
1824: 1823
1831: 1830
1833: 1832
1840: 1839
1849: 1848
1856: 1855
1858: 1857
1865: 1864
1874: 1873
1881: 1880
1883: 1882
1890: 1889
1899: 1898
1906: 1905
1908: 1907
1915: 1914
1924: 1923
1931: 1930
1933: 1932
1940: 1939
1949: 1948
1956: 1955
1958: 1957
1965: 1964
1974: 1973
1981: 1980
1983: 1982
1990: 1989
1999: 1998
2006: 2005
2008: 2007
2015: 2014
2024: 2023
2031: 2030
2033: 2032
2040: 2039
3205: 3204
3212: 3211
3216: 3215
3223: 3222
3230: 3229
3237: 3236
3241: 3240
3248: 3247
3255: 3254
3262: 3261
3266: 3265
3273: 3272
3280: 3279
3287: 3286
3291: 3290
3298: 3297
3305: 3304
3312: 3311
3316: 3315
3323: 3322
3330: 3329
3337: 3336
3341: 3340
3348: 3347
3355: 3354
3362: 3361
3366: 3365
3373: 3372
3380: 3379
3387: 3386
3391: 3390
3398: 3397
3405: 3404
3412: 3411
3416: 3415
3423: 3422
3430: 3429
3437: 3436
3441: 3440
3448: 3447
3455: 3454
3462: 3461
3466: 3465
3473: 3472
3480: 3479
3487: 3486
3491: 3490
3498: 3497
3505: 3504
3512: 3511
3516: 3515
3523: 3522
3530: 3529
3537: 3536
3541: 3540
3548: 3547
3555: 3554
3562: 3561
3566: 3565
3573: 3572
3580: 3579
3587: 3586
3591: 3590
3598: 3597
3605: 3604
3612: 3611
3616: 3615
3623: 3622
3630: 3629
3637: 3636
3641: 3640
3648: 3647
3655: 3654
3662: 3661
3666: 3665
3673: 3672
3680: 3679
3687: 3686
3691: 3690
3698: 3697
3705: 3704
3712: 3711
3716: 3715
3723: 3722
3730: 3729
3737: 3736
3741: 3740
3748: 3747
3755: 3754
3762: 3761
3766: 3765
3773: 3772
3780: 3779
3787: 3786
3791: 3790
3798: 3797
3805: 3804
3812: 3811
3816: 3815
3823: 3822
3830: 3829
3837: 3836
3841: 3840
3848: 3847
3855: 3854
3862: 3861
3866: 3865
3873: 3872
3880: 3879
3887: 3886
3891: 3890
3898: 3897
3905: 3904
3912: 3911
3916: 3915
3923: 3922
3930: 3929
3937: 3936
3941: 3940
3948: 3947
3955: 3954
3962: 3961
3966: 3965
3973: 3972
3980: 3979
3987: 3986
3991: 3990
3998: 3997
4005: 4004
4012: 4011
4016: 4015
4023: 4022
4030: 4029
4037: 4036
4041: 4040
4048: 4047
4055: 4054
4062: 4061
4066: 4065
4073: 4072
4080: 4079
4087: 4086
4091: 4090
6407: 6406
6410: 6409
6421: 6420
6424: 6423
6432: 6431
6435: 6434
6446: 6445
6449: 6448
6457: 6456
6460: 6459
6471: 6470
6474: 6473
6482: 6481
6485: 6484
6496: 6495
6499: 6498
6507: 6506
6510: 6509
6521: 6520
6524: 6523
6532: 6531
6535: 6534
6546: 6545
6549: 6548
6557: 6556
6560: 6559
6571: 6570
6574: 6573
6582: 6581
6585: 6584
6596: 6595
6599: 6598
6607: 6606
6610: 6609
6621: 6620
6624: 6623
6632: 6631
6635: 6634
6646: 6645
6649: 6648
6657: 6656
6660: 6659
6671: 6670
6674: 6673
6682: 6681
6685: 6684
6696: 6695
6699: 6698
6707: 6706
6710: 6709
6721: 6720
6724: 6723
6732: 6731
6735: 6734
6746: 6745
6749: 6748
6757: 6756
6760: 6759
6771: 6770
6774: 6773
6782: 6781
6785: 6784
6796: 6795
6799: 6798
6807: 6806
6810: 6809
6821: 6820
6824: 6823
6832: 6831
6835: 6834
6846: 6845
6849: 6848
6857: 6856
6860: 6859
6871: 6870
6874: 6873
6882: 6881
6885: 6884
6896: 6895
6899: 6898
6907: 6906
6910: 6909
6921: 6920
6924: 6923
6932: 6931
6935: 6934
6946: 6945
6949: 6948
6957: 6956
6960: 6959
6971: 6970
6974: 6973
6982: 6981
6985: 6984
6996: 6995
6999: 6998
7007: 7006
7010: 7009
7021: 7020
7024: 7023
7032: 7031
7035: 7034
7046: 7045
7049: 7048
7057: 7056
7060: 7059
7071: 7070
7074: 7073
7082: 7081
7085: 7084
7096: 7095
7099: 7098
7107: 7106
7110: 7109
7121: 7120
7124: 7123
7132: 7131
7135: 7134
7146: 7145
7149: 7148
7157: 7156
7160: 7159
7171: 7170
7174: 7173
7182: 7181
7185: 7184
7196: 7195
7199: 7198
7207: 7206
7210: 7209
7221: 7220
7224: 7223
7232: 7231
7235: 7234
7246: 7245
7249: 7248
7257: 7256
7260: 7259
7271: 7270
7274: 7273
7282: 7281
7285: 7284
7296: 7295
7299: 7298
7307: 7306
7310: 7309
7321: 7320
7324: 7323
7332: 7331
7335: 7334
7346: 7345
7349: 7348
7357: 7356
7360: 7359
7371: 7370
7374: 7373
7382: 7381
7385: 7384
7396: 7395
7399: 7398
7407: 7406
7410: 7409
7421: 7420
7424: 7423
7432: 7431
7435: 7434
7446: 7445
7449: 7448
7457: 7456
7460: 7459
7471: 7470
7474: 7473
7482: 7481
7485: 7484
7496: 7495
7499: 7498
7507: 7506
7510: 7509
7521: 7520
7524: 7523
7532: 7531
7535: 7534
7546: 7545
7549: 7548
7557: 7556
7560: 7559
7571: 7570
7574: 7573
7582: 7581
7585: 7584
7596: 7595
7599: 7598
7607: 7606
7610: 7609
7621: 7620
7624: 7623
7632: 7631
7635: 7634
7646: 7645
7649: 7648
7657: 7656
7660: 7659
7671: 7670
7674: 7673
7682: 7681
7685: 7684
7696: 7695
7699: 7698
7707: 7706
7710: 7709
7721: 7720
7724: 7723
7732: 7731
7735: 7734
7746: 7745
7749: 7748
7757: 7756
7760: 7759
7771: 7770
7774: 7773
7782: 7781
7785: 7784
7796: 7795
7799: 7798
7807: 7806
7810: 7809
7821: 7820
7824: 7823
7832: 7831
7835: 7834
7846: 7845
7849: 7848
7857: 7856
7860: 7859
7871: 7870
7874: 7873
7882: 7881
7885: 7884
7896: 7895
7899: 7898
7907: 7906
7910: 7909
7921: 7920
7924: 7923
7932: 7931
7935: 7934
7946: 7945
7949: 7948
7957: 7956
7960: 7959
7971: 7970
7974: 7973
7982: 7981
7985: 7984
7996: 7995
7999: 7998
8007: 8006
8010: 8009
8021: 8020
8024: 8023
8032: 8031
8035: 8034
8046: 8045
8049: 8048
8057: 8056
8060: 8059
8071: 8070
8074: 8073
8082: 8081
8085: 8084
8096: 8095
8099: 8098
8107: 8106
8110: 8109
8121: 8120
8124: 8123
8132: 8131
8135: 8134
8146: 8145
8149: 8148
8157: 8156
8160: 8159
8171: 8170
8174: 8173
8182: 8181
8185: 8184
```

That is 573 times, i.e. 5.73% of the time.